# How to show search result hyperlinks in Modal dialog

Tags: 2013, search, modal-dialog

Can anyone help me with issue about opening search result hyperlinks in modal dialog page.

In default every pages are opening in separate html page. Im aiming to same dialog as is used in list webparts.

For example: https://eudeska.justice.cz/vysledky-hledani?k=test%20search%20result

Is it possible by editing Item_CommonItem_Body.html in Display Templates of search results?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it is to modify a copy of item template, but otherwise you are right. My item template for basic Tasks do open the link in a dialog box, and returns to the search page when the dialog closes, super easy for the end user